# `mdworker_shared` processes using up all CPU but can’t find what Spotlight is indexing?

Tags: spotlight

This seems like a recurrent question on apple SE: `mdworker_shared` processes have a tendency to use a lot of CPU cycles, which degrades performance. I’m running macOS Monterey 12.5.1 (21G83).

Based on previous answers, I’ve tried to see which files were indexed by using these commands but can’t see any indexing going on.

```
sudo fs_usage mdworker mds
sudo fs_usage -w -f filesys mds
```

I can confirm it’s really Spotlight indexing that’s causing the problem because turning it off with `sudo mdutil -a -i off` solves the issue. But obviously I’d like to avoid disabling Spotlight altogether as several apps rely on it (e.g. Alfred, etc.)

I have also tried rebuilding the entire file index, no luck either. And the file index doesn’t seem to be corrupted.

Is there *anything* I can try to avoid Spotlight using resources while I’m working? This doesn’t just happen when macOS is idle, it happens any moment while I’m actively using my macbook.